Cypress does not log in by cy.setCookie() in AzureDevOps project
I am trying to run automation tests with cypress in a project set up by interns at the company I myself is now an intern at. The website uses OAuth 2.0 and AAD for the login process and there is currently no API POST endpoint for the login. When I try to reach the login page I get caught in an infinite redirection loop that ends in error 414, so to avoid this I am trying to set the cookie with the JWT token that the login process creates before getting to the website.
This is my code
describe('Mock authentication so I can test the website', () => {
  beforeEach(() =>{
    cy.clearCookies();
  })
  it('Visits BoostApps dev site', () => {
    cy.viewport(1200,1800)
    
    cy.setCookie('access_token', 'Token is placed here', {
      domain: 'url to website',
      path: '/',
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
    });
    
    cy.debug().getCookie('access_token')
    
    cy.visit('url to website', {
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }); 

    cy.contains('Competitions').click() //Competitions are only available for logged in users
  });
});

When running this with a newly generated token from Postman I get the following error
! CypressError

cy.setCookie() had an unexpected error setting the requested cookie in Chrome.

> Error: Sanitizing cookie failed

I have set chromeWebSecurity: false in my config file
Tried solution 1
I have tried using different browsers with third party cookies allowed
same results
Tried solution 2
I have tried using c.origin() in different ways
same results
I have also tried a huge number of other small solutions in code differences supplied to me by Chatgpt. I am fairly new to testing and very new to cypress. My coding knowledge is fairly low so I am wondering if anyone else have encountered this issue or if there is a good way to go through with the authorization without using the login ui.

It will be some bad formatting in the token.
Take a look at these tests:
Well formed token
it('sets a well-formed token in a cookie', () => {
  const token = '123'
  cy.setCookie('test', token)
})



Malformed token
it('sets a badly-formed token in a cookie', () => {

  // multi-line token string 
  const token = `  
  123`
  cy.setCookie('test', token)
})

This throws the same error you have:


The token is formulated in a single line and even if I define it as a named variable like your example I still get the same outcome.
The token is very big so I don't know if the token itself becomes weird, but since it's only copypaste that should not be the case

Yet you have an error - something in that token is not correct.

BTW using a variable makes no difference to the outcome, I just use it to make the example clearer.

If it is the token that is bad it must be the name of the token then. The entire project is hosted on Azure and the login process is done through login.microsoftonline.com and uses AAD and OAuth2.0 to give a JWTtoken to authenticate the user. When I try to find the cookie where the token is saved it can only be session storage. Everything I try from there results in the same error. Besides the error points to the s in setCookies.

Sorry your comment does not shed any light on the problem for me. Name of the toekn doesn't matter, and where the error points is just indicating that setCookie() is the command that's failing. We would need more details to answer fully, if the token is confidential you will just have to experiment with the code I gave above.

The token is generated in Postman and is only valid for about an hour so it's not neccesarily confidential. What I ment about the name of the token is the actual name of the cookie (in your example 'token'). Every example I've looked at have shown a completely different way of showing the cookie so I'm only like 85% sure that the name is correct. But every other option I've tried ended in the same result.

Ok, I get the part about the name now - but the error seems to be thrown outside of the Azure context (and independent of the name) - my test is not even visiting a web site, I just give a malformed token to setCookie() and I get the error.

Well I don't see how else I can formulate it and still have it be the token I need. I'll go with a different route then. Thanks for the help.
